# Issue while sending email in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am getting the exception as

> Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: Sorry, your
>   envelope sender is in my badmailfrom list.

Here is the code to send the email

```
public void SendEmail()
    {
        try
        {
            string Smtp_Client = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Smtp_Client"];
            string NewtwrkCredentials_Uname = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewtwrkCredentials_Uname"];
            string NewtwrkCredentials_P = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewtwrkCredentials_P"];

            //Declaration a list of attendees
            MailAddressCollection macCollection = new MailAddressCollection();
            //Add attendde. In this example, I send invite to only one
            macCollection.Add(new MailAddress("****@****.com"));
            //Create mail message
            MailMessage mmMessage = formMailMessage("Test", "Test", "***.***@gmail.com", macCollection);
            //Create smtp client
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtpout.europe.secureserver.net", 25);
            //Configure your smtp client
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("****@*****.com", "****");
            //Send it
            smtp.Send(mmMessage);

        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {

        }

    }

    public static MailMessage formMailMessage(string strSubject, string strBodyHTML, string Email, MailAddressCollection macAttendeeList)
    {
        //Create an instance of mail message
        MailMessage mmMessage = new MailMessage();
        //  Set up the different mime types contained in the message
        System.Net.Mime.ContentType typeText = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/plain");
        System.Net.Mime.ContentType typeHTML = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");

        AlternateView viewHTML = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(strBodyHTML, typeHTML);
        mmMessage.AlternateViews.Add(viewHTML);
        //Adress the message
        mmMessage.From = new MailAddress(Email);
        foreach (MailAddress attendee in macAttendeeList)
        {
            mmMessage.To.Add(attendee);
        }
        mmMessage.Subject = strSubject;
        return mmMessage;
    }
```

Can anyone help me with the code as to what am i doing wrong? i created a console application and used the same piece of code and it worked fine. the smtp server, network credentials are all proper.

Kindly Help

Comment: Try again with an other sender. It's an issue of the server, it doesn't allow the specified sender.

Comment: Might be a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282602/system-net-mail-smtpfailedrecipientexception-mailbox-name-not-allowed

Comment: the current sender is in server blacklist,try another sender.

Comment: The error message says it all: "The server response was: Sorry, your envelope sender is in my badmailfrom list." The server rejects this sender.

Comment: Did the console app you tested use the same SMTP server and login credentials for it?

Comment: @Chris Yes the same ones, no change at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what the issue was i used a different smtp server and the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what the error says the from address is in a black list of email addresses.

If you have a system administrator who manages the server contact them to resolve this, or use another address to send it from.

If it's a hosted service contact the provider and notify them and ask them what credentials to use.

Comment: To me this doesn't explain why the same code failed from one location but not another. I'd imagine either the sender is being set implicitly in some way or the error is actually looking at IP address as well as sender. I don't think this is a good answer without addressing the discrepancy...

Comment: It depends entirely on where the code is called from, if the console application is on a server then it may bypass the requirement for the auth. We've had entire IP ranges in a company where auth was not required as it was trusted, it may have even been routed to another server. He needs to contact the admin to see about this.